# How would I solve for the limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need help understanding this conceptually. I need to find the limit of

> $$f(x) = \lim_{x\to ∞} (\sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 1} - x)$$

I so far multiplied by the conjugate (to make it easier to work with) to yield an answer of
$$f(x) = \lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{6x + 1}{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 1}}$$

And I've been told to factor out the $x$ from the radical and then from the numerator and denominator to get
$$f(x) = \lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{x(6 + \frac{1}{x})}{x (1 + \sqrt{1 + \frac{6}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}})}$$

And this is where I'm stuck.

Essentially, I just want to understand two things: *why factor out the $x$,* and *what should I do next to find the limit of this function?*

Any step towards the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now you eliminate the $x$ from the numerator and denominator. Taking limits at $x\to \infty$, we will have $\frac1x\to 0$.

Comment: @player3236 How did $\frac{1}{x}$ turn into $0$?

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac1x = 0$. When $x$ gets larger and larger, $\dfrac1x$ gets smaller and smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're factoring out the $x$ in order to get an idea of what the limit might "look like". In this case, once you divide the numerator and the denominator by $x$, you get

$$\frac{6 + \frac{1}{x}}{1+ \sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$

Now, since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$, the numerator goes to 6 as $x \to \infty$.  Since $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}} = 1$, the denominator goes to $2$ as $x \to \infty$. So the "whole thing" goes to $\frac{6}{2} = 3$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: How does the $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} = 0$? I can't seem to wrap my head around this concept.

Comment: Don't worry,  you'll wrap your heads around this in no time. To show "some thing" goes to $0$, I need to show that it becomes arbitrarily small. That is, given any $\epsilon > 0$, I need to show that it is eventually smaller than $\epsilon$. Can you show that $\frac{1}{x} < \epsilon$ after some point?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x} < \epsilon$ would be true before $\epsilon = 1$ (?). As it gets smaller than $1$, it eventually gets smaller than $\epsilon$. This is the concept of $\lim_{x\to 0}$? (I just realized that my question before was a typo - I meant how does $\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{1}{x} = 0$).

Comment: But I think I can connect your explanation to the concept for $\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{1}{x} = 0$ - as $x$ approaches infinity, $\frac{1}{x}$ would approach $0$, so therefore $\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{1}{x} = 0$ is true?

Comment: Yes that is the correct way of looking at it